# Combo box which has the option of to type an entry, in HTML

Tags: php, html, combobox

A combo box which has the option of to type an entry works correctly in HTML, but the problem I have now is if you have too many data of to display no scroll bar found there means that there are many data which are displayed out of screen.

```
<input type="text" name="example" list="exList">
<datalist id="exList">
    <option value="1">
    <option value="2">
    <option value="3">
    <option value="4">
    <option value="n">
</datalist>
```

Please anyone can help me.

Comment: Are you adding the value entered into the text input to the options?

Comment: I add the value, or select in the existing values.

Comment: It is not to add values there, I only want to select or type. But not type and save to existing ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php $cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota"); ?>

<script>
  function getOptions()
  {
      document.getElementById("sel1").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
  function addtext(a)
  {
     document.getElementById("txt1").value = a.innerHTML;
     document.getElementById("sel1").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
</script>

<input type="text" name="txt1" id="txt1" onClick="getOptions()"><br/>
<select id="sel1" size="4" style="width:150px;visibility:hidden;" >
<?php 
   foreach($cars as $x => $x_value) 
   {
      echo "<option onClick='addtext(this)' value=".$x.">".$x_value."</option>";
   }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Here in my example option values are fixed defined in $cars, if you want it dynamic then fetch the values from database,..

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to add scrollbar to DataList because it does not support any css properties, so one way is that you can use dropdownlist, 

`<select>
<option/>
</select>`. Scrollbar automatically added to dropdownlist..

Comment: That is good, but you cannot use combo box as combo box and Text box. Is there any idea?.